# "Missing required key 'Bucket'" when using AWS Amplify Storage

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm having trouble with basic usage of Amplify's `Storage` in React Native.

Here is my setup:

```
Storage.configure({
  AWSS3: {
    bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    region: 'us-east-2'
  }
})
```

And then I try doing a simple `.get()` call like so:

```
Storage.get('my-file.json')
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

But I end up with an error like this:

```
{
  "[WARN] 21:31.529 StorageClass - get signed url error": [MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params],
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!